# Vector C++ size and access elements

Tags: c++, vector

I have this in a code

```
vector<vector<double> > times(pCount, vector<double>(5,0.0));
```

My question is, what is size of the matrix it is allocating ? If I need to access all the values in them what can I do ?

Comment: Looking at [what the constructor does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for `std::vector` what do you think it is?

Comment: and ask yourself whether it's row stack or column stack....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `pCount × 5` matrix. The first index can be between 0 and `pCount - 1` (inclusive), the second index can be between 0 and 4 (inclusive). All the values are initialized to 0.

This is because you're using the std::vector constructor whose first argument is a count `n` (the number of elements to initialize the vector with), and whose second argument is a value which is copied `n` times. So, `times` is a vector with `pCount` elements, each of which is a `vector<double>`. Each of those vectors is a copy of the provided `vector<double>(5,0.0)`, which is constructed with 5 elements, each of which is 0.0.

You can get any individual value like `times[3][2]`, or what-have-you. With C++11 or later you can iterate through all the values like this:

```
for (auto& v : times)
    for (double& d : v)
        d += 3.14; // or whatever
```

If you don't need to modify the values, but only access them, you can remove the ampersands, or better yet do:

```
for (const auto& v : times)
    for (double d : v)
        std::cout << d << ", "; // or whatever
```

Before C++11, you have to be much more wordy, or just use indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pCount; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        times[i][j] += 3.14; // or whatever
```

Comment: Just picking a little nit; Why not use `auto` for the nested range for as well?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Well, for simple types, I like to see what it is. For instance, adding 3.14 wouldn't make much sense if it wasn't floating-point. And in the second example I use `double d` instead of `const double& d` because copying a built-in is cheaper than using a reference, but if `d` was something else that wouldn't be true.

Comment: @NathanOliver, agree with Kundor. When types are simple and known, it's best to name them. Helps future code readers. However, passing double by value is often cheaper, than passing it by reference :) (depending on optimizer's mood, of course)

Comment: `times[i].size()` should really be used as the condition for the inner loop in the before C++11 example instead of a static `5`, being vectors the valid range can be modified.

Comment: @SergeyA Meh.  It makes maintainability harder since you have to remember to change the type in the for loop.  Personally I would stick to auto unless you need to cast.  if you "know" what the the type is of the outer loop using auto then you know what the inner type is as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I find it to be mostly a matter of personal choice, not worth arguing about. But I would do the same as Kundor.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You could say it makes maintainability _easier_ since e.g. after changing the type of the vectors to `int`, a compiler error ("invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `'double&'`…") will remind you that adding 3.14 doesn't make sense anymore. (With `auto` it just silently truncates.)

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent in size to a standard array of `[pCount][5]`

```
double[pCount][5] = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},  // |
                     {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},  // |
                     {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},  // | pCount = 5
                     {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},  // |
                     {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}; // |
```

Of course, you're using vectors, so the number of rows and columns can be variable after `times` is created.

`std::vector` includes an override for [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), so you can access data using that operator.

`auto Val = times[2][3]`

Comment: The `|` look like a special syntax, you should use a comment.

Comment: Actually it's bit bigger. This example has one `vector<vector<double>` that contains 5 `vector<double>`, so there are 6 `vector`s in addition to the storage used by the 5 `vector<double>`s. Size of `vector` may differ from one implementation to another. Also note that the storage of the 5 `vector<double>`s is not contiguous like in the array example.

Comment: @user4581301 My assumption when they said `size` was the number of double elements allocated, not the size of the `vectors` themselves. But yes, there is a chance more memory is utilized as overhead for maintaining the vectors depending on implementation. The memory is also not contiguous, but is accessable as if it were due to the overloaded `operator[]`, but block memory operations such as `memset` won't work (but shouldn't be used on vectors anyway)

Comment: While equivalent in size, not really equivalent in one important aspect - the matrix above is contiguous in memory, while vector of vectors is not.

Comment: @cocarin True enough. I got a bit pedantic there.